# Calculation of euclidean distances with awk not giving the expected output

Tags: awk, distance, calculation

as input for the distance calulation I have a file (inp.txt) containing the coordinates:

```
9.911 -2.781 30.097 7.768 -4.335 29.094
11.811 -1.900 30.082 13.294 -1.993 27.440
6.947 -0.742 31.786 6.390 -2.976 30.089
8.960 -2.090 32.359 11.764 1.604 25.408
9.156 -3.314 29.815 11.764 1.604 25.408
```

The first three columns are the coordinates of a point (let'say A) while the last three are the coordinates of a second point (let'say B). I want to calculate the distance between A and B and all the other points arranged in the same way in the following rows. Then, I expect as output 5 distance values, in this case.

My awk code I am using for this aim:

```
awk '{x1=$1;y1=$2;z1=$3} {x2=$4;y2=$5;z2=$6} END{print sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 + (z1-z2)^2)}' inp.txt >> out.txt
```

Entering it I get the error:

```
 awk: fatal: cannot open file `{x1=$1;y1=$2;z1=$3} {x2=$4;y2=$5;z2=$6} END{print sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 + (z1-z2)^2)}' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

I tried to figure out why I get this error with no success.
Thank for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the input file in the place where you think it is? Your script works for me with inp.txt in the current directory. If I reference a bad filename on purpose there's an error similar to yours:

```
t2$ awk '{x1=$1;y1=$2;z1=$3} {x2=$4;y2=$5;z2=$6} {print sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 + (z1-z2)^2)}' inpBAD.txt
awk: fatal: cannot open file `inpBAD.txt' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

Also, you probably don't want the END condition there, if you're expecting a value for every row, not just the last one...

```
t2$ awk '{x1=$1;y1=$2;z1=$3} {x2=$4;y2=$5;z2=$6} END{print sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 + (z1-z2)^2)}' inp.txt
7.1

t2$ awk '{x1=$1;y1=$2;z1=$3} {x2=$4;y2=$5;z2=$6} {print sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 + (z1-z2)^2)}' inp.txt
2.83079
3.03119
2.86021
8.3561
7.1
```

Comment: Thanks Ian. Yes it was a bad filename. Sorry for the silly question. Anyway, you helped me with the iteration as well. Could you explain why the END hampers the iteration in awk? I thought was mandattory instead for my purposes.

Comment: No, a bad or missing file name did not cause you to get an error message of ```awk: fatal: cannot open file `{x1=$1;y1=$2;z1=$3} {x2=$4;y2=$5;z2=$6} END{print sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 + (z1-z2)^2)}' for reading (No such file or directory)```.

Comment: Thanks Ed, your answer is actually the correct one here, you get my upvote.  Maurizio, the END condition is only true after all lines have been read - the action after end is triggered at that point.  If you want to process on every input line, then no need for the END in this script.  It's typically used when you want to summarize some data and then show the summary information.

Answer (score 1):

You did `awk -f '{x1=$1;...}'` or `awk 'foo' '{x1=$1;...}'` instead of `awk '{x1=$1;...}'` so awk was trying to open the script as if it was the name of a file. The latter is more likely given that specific error message. Look:

```
$ awk -f '{x1=$1;y1=$2;z1=$3} {x2=$4;y2=$5;z2=$6} END{print sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 + (z1-z2)^2)}' inp.txt >> out.txt
awk: fatal: cannot open source file `{x1=$1;y1=$2;z1=$3} {x2=$4;y2=$5;z2=$6} END{print sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 + (z1-z2)^2)}' for reading: No such file or directory

$ awk '7' '{x1=$1;y1=$2;z1=$3} {x2=$4;y2=$5;z2=$6} END{print sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 + (z1-z2)^2)}' inp.txt >> out.txt
awk: fatal: cannot open file `{x1=$1;y1=$2;z1=$3} {x2=$4;y2=$5;z2=$6} END{print sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 + (z1-z2)^2)}' for reading: No such file or directory
```